# Why does trap not get triggered when sourcing a file that does not exist?

Tags: bash, error-handling, trap

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eEuo pipefail
set -x

function deploy_cleanup(){
    echo "---Cleaning up---"
    echo "hello"
}

trap deploy_cleanup ERR

whoami
source euaueoaue
```

Outputs:

```
+ trap deploy_cleanup ERR
+ whoami
chris
+ source euaueoaue
./xx.sh: line 14: euaueoaue: No such file or directory
```

Is `source` somehow a special case? The exit code is `1` in any case.

---

If I remove the `set -e` then it seems to work correctly:

```
+ trap deploy_cleanup ERR
+ whoami
chris
+ source euaueoaue
./xx.sh: line 14: euaueoaue: No such file or directory
++ deploy_cleanup
++ echo '---Cleaning up---'
---Cleaning up---
++ echo hello
hello
```